# stop Android wifi auto scanning programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi

The wifi in my android device is automatically scanning each several seconds if wifi is not connected.
I tried to stop that using the following:
I tried to run an app with a `WifiManager.createWifiLock()` and `acquire()`, however, that doesn't seem to work.

please let me know why my method is not working.and is there a way to achieve that?